# Add a letter to the last \ in each line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, line, addition, letter

I would like to add a letter before the last `\` in each line in Notepad++, like this:

before :

```
product\190\1017\evita-cover-art.jpg
```

after :

```
product\190\1017b\evita-cover-art.jpg
```

So the letter `b` is added before the last `\` ,

There are many lines, so I would use find and replace with regex probably.

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\\[^\\]*$`
- Replace with: `b$0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\\          # a backslash
[^\\]*      # 0 or more any character that is not a backslash
$           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
b           # literally
$0          # content of group 0 (i.e. the whole match)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]